# Upgrade Ender 3 with Diamond Hotend

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply, diamond-hotend

As I want to print with multiple colors I plan to upgrade my Ender 3 with the [diamond hotend](https://reprap.org/wiki/Diamond_Hotend#Electronics_setup).

So far I found all information I need, except what power supply I need for my [RUMBA board](https://reprap.org/wiki/RUMBA).

Can I use the default Ender 3 power supply or do I need an additional power supply or wires?

Parts I am going to order:

- 1x Lite6 Heatsink
- 3x Diamond Universal mount
- 1x 12 V 40 W 6 mm x 20 mm Cartridge Heater Reprap For 3D Printer
- 1x Thermistor 100K 1 % NTC Temperature Sensor Line for 3D Printer
- 1x Fan 50x50x15 mm 12 V 125 mA
- 1x Diamond Hotend Insulator
- 1x Nema17 stepper motor 48 mm 1.8° 42BYGHW804 1.2 A 5.5 kg•cm
- 3x MK8/9 Dual Extruder Feed Device Part For 3D Printer 1.75 mm Filament
- 3x Bowden tube 1 m with fitting 4/2 mm (for 1.75 mm filament)
- 1x RUMBA 3D printer controller board
- 6x StepStick DRV8825 Stepper Motor Driver

Comment: Ender 3 is a 24v printer so you have to address the heater and fans at minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RUMBA boards run up to 36 V, so reusing the (24 V) power supply from your printer should be fine. As the 2 extra steppers do not take much extra power (note you are ordering only 1!), your supply should be sufficient. Note that a 12 V heater cartridge is not going to work on a 24 V board (you'll get a massive overshoot and probably over-temperature warnings and printer shutdowns).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped me. I changed the 12 V heater cartridge to 24 V and added two extra stepper motors.

Comment: @Janik In total you need 3 stepper motors, you could salvage 1 from the current extruder,so that you need to order 2 not 3. But, I would also order 3 to have 3 the same.